# Gzip compressed each files with .gz Extension how to revert back

Tags: 14.04, compression, zip, gzip

I am trying to do a zip project folder and by mistake used

```
gzip -r /project1. gz /project1
```

and it has been zipped each files with.gz extension how I can revert it back.

Please advise.

```
/app# ls

associations.js.gz  middlewares.js.gz  util.js.gz

components          notifier.js.gz     validators.js.gz
```

Comment: Please open a teminal, change the directory to the directory you were when you ran the command and post the output of `ls` and `ls /`, just to be sure.

Comment: Given above $ gzip -r /project1.gz /project1

Comment: /app# ls
associations.js.gz  middlewares.js.gz  util.js.gz
components          notifier.js.gz     validators.js.gz

Comment: Please post also the output of `ls /`.

Comment: ls output are like :

_associations.js.gz  middlewares.js.gz  util.js.gz_

_components          notifier.js.gz     validators.js.gz_

Comment: That's the output of `ls`, not the output of `ls /` (mind the slash at the end). The first one shows the content of your current working directory, the second one shows the content of `/`, which is what I'd like to see, since the command you ran could have affected folders inside it.

Comment: Please see its output: ls LiveApp/project1 / 
    LiveApp/project1:
AndroidManifest.xml.gz  gen                     lint.xml.gz              res
assets                  ic_launcher-web.png.gz  proguard-project.txt.gz  src
bin                     libs                    project.properties.gz
root@fileserver:/# ^C

Comment: That's the output of `ls /LiveApp/LiveApp/`. Please run this *exact* command: `ls /`, from whatever directory you want.

Comment: root@fileserver:/LiveApp/project1# ls / 
bin   cdrom  etc         home        lib      lost+found  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  dev     initrd.img  LiveApp  media       opt  root  sbin  sys  usr  vmlinuz
root@fileserver:/LiveApp/project1#  is ok now?

Comment: Yes, the only thing missing is: where is the `/app` folder shown in the prompt? Apparently you don't have it in `/`. In which path did you run the command exactly? Also are you sure that's the exact command you ran? That command run in the directory shown in `ls`'s output shouldn't have affected anything. Are you sure the `.` in the command wasn't detached from `/project1`? That would explain what happened. Can you check your command history?

Comment: root@fileserver:/LiveApp/project1# ls app /
app:
associations.js.gz  middlewares.js.gz  util.js.gz
components          notifier.js.gz     validators.js.gz
root@fileserver:/LiveApp/project1#

Comment: root@fileserver:/LiveApp/project1/app# ls /
bin   cdrom  etc         home        lib      lost+found  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  dev     initrd.img  LiveApp  media       opt  root  sbin  sys  usr  vmlinuz
root@fileserver:/LiveApp/project1/app#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uncompress all files by using

```
gzip -rd /project1. gz /project1
```

It's the same command you used for compression but with a added `d` option fpr decompression.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple, all you need to do is right click the file you want to get back to its original state and look for "extract here" click that then in the folder you extracted it from, it will be placed in there, and if you want to .gz .tar .zip ect again in the same folder it was compressed in. hope i helped

Comment: This is Ubuntu VPS Server Can't access it graphically.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry never used Vps before